# AutoFilterRow not working for focused Detail Grid View

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a master-detail grid control. I have added the auto filter row to both the master and detail views.

When I try to use the filter row for detail view, the view is unchanged i.e. seems like the filter is not applied to the focused view. However, the other expanded detail views (Synchronization is true) changes as per this filter text.

If I collapse and expand the master row again, the filter is applied correctly but still I am not able to update the view based on the autofilterrow.

Please help me here. I feel like I'm missing some event handling or some basic property here.

Comment: Have you tried to [contact the DevExpress Support Team directly](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create)?

Comment: Yes. I have raised a ticket there with the same question.